# lsblk lists a device, then says "not a device"

Tags: linux, block-device, lsblk

I'm seeing somewhat odd behaviour:

```
% lsblk | grep sdb                                 
sdb                      8:16   1 114.6G  0 disk  
└─sdb1                   8:17   1 114.6G  0 part  /run/media/ravi/CC49-1FC8
% lsblk /dev/sdb  
lsblk: /dev/sdb: not a block device
```

The device is a newly ordered [Sandisk dual USB-C 128GB](https://www.sandisk.com/home/mobile-device-storage/ultra-dual-drive-usb-type-c) that I'm running [`f3write`](https://fight-flash-fraud.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)  on to check if it is a fake or not.

Why would `lsblk` contradict itself like this?

Are there different measures as to what is a block device?

Answer (score 2):

`lsblk` on its own will scan for devices in `sysfs`. Many linux distributions have a hotplug handler (`udev`) that automagically makes corresponding nodes in `/dev` when block devices appear, and removes them when the devices disappear.

Either your system doesn't have such hotplug handler, or more likely there is one, but it fails to handle the hotplugging event, so you have ended up without the corresponding `/dev` node. For the latter, perhaps the system log file(s) have some indication about that failure.