# fdisk prints nothing and devices are not mounted

Tags: block-device, lsblk

I am quite new to Linux, and I need to mount some devices, using the `lsblk` command and more.
`lsblk` presents the devices (internal, I don't have external ones) the output is:

```
# lsblk
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                       8:0    0   120G  0 disk
|_sda1                    8:1    0     2G  0 part
|_sda2                    8:2    0   118G  0 part
  |_centos-root (dm-0)  253:0    0   110G  0 lvm  /opt/loglevels
  |_centos-swap (dm-1)  253:1    0     8G  0 lvm
sr0                      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I saw in many tutorials that the devices are mounted to /dev directory, i.e to get the sda1 device I'd type `lsblk /dev/sda1` etc. but this command returns `lsblk: /dev/sda1: not a block device` 
when I type `fdisk -l` that brings the mounted devices- it prints nothing:

```
# fdisk -l
#
```

where is my mistake? what am I missing? I saw [in this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508901/lsblk-lists-a-device-then-says-not-a-device) that there might be some problem in mounting the files, how can I see it?
Thaks a lot!

Comment: Welcome, `/dev/<device>` are representations of devices, they are not mounted there. You mount them in a directory of your choosing, as in `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`. then you can access the data in the device in the `/mnt` directory.

Comment: /dev/sda1 is not a block device indeed, but the first partition on that device. /dev/sda is the device.

Answer (score -1):

For `lsblk` consider doing this

```
alias lsblk2='lsblk -o type,name,label,partlabel,size,fstype,model,serial,wwn,uuid'
```

That sets up an alias so when you type `lsblk2` it will give what i consider the most useful printout of what lsblk can do, and show all devices connected that you can easily reference and know what is what.

And doing `lsblk -h` will give you the help printout, showing all the options you can use like I did with the lsblk2 alias, and you can tweak to your liking.

Comment: i must have typo'd, it works now.

Comment: I don't see how the above command can help me, besides- the columns `patlabel, serial,wwn,uuid` are not detected.

Comment: if lsblk doesn't identify the disk then it is not connected to the system where linux can access it.  It has nothing to do with *internal* or *external*.  It works for me for sata disks connected sata ports or will show the block device {volume} presented by a raid controller, or any *external* usb connected disk.